# Como deixo um RadioButton marcado como default?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tenho vários radioButton's. Como faço pra deixar um marcado como default?

```
private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    comboBox4.Visible = false;
    comboBox5.Visible = false;
    comboBox6.Visible = false;
    comboBox7.Visible = false;
}// RadioButton.Checked
```

Answer (score 7):

Para deixar um RadioButton marcado é só alterar sua propriedade Checked para `true`. Você pode fazer isso na janela Propriedades ou via código como, por exemplo, no evento Load de seu formulário:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    seuRadioButton.Checked = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma propriedade no proprio componente: Cheked(true ou false)

> ```
> private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
>     comboBox4.Visible = false;
>     comboBox5.Visible = false;
>     comboBox6.Visible = false;
>     comboBox7.Visible = false;
> }// RadioButton.Checked
> ```

```
    Radio4.Cheked = true;
    Radio5.Cheked = true;
    Radio6.Cheked = true;
    Radio7.Cheked = true;
```